# I want to plot row means of multiple columns as geom_line and standard deviation with geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-deviation

I managed to plot the means as a line, however, I do not know how to plot their respective standard deviation as geom_smooth.

When I just use the geom_smooth function, it does not seem to plot the correct standard deviation.

This is my code so far:

```
library("ggplot2")

df <- data.frame(wue_r$WUE19, wue_r$WUE27, wue_r$WUE16, wue_r$WUE17)

mean <- rowMeans(df)

wue_fin<-cbind(wue_r, means = mean)

colors <- c("WUE16"="chartreuse", "WUE19"="chartreuse3",  "WUE27"="darkgreen", "WUE17"="darkolivegreen", "means"="black")

plot1 <- ggplot(wue_fin, aes(x=Year)) +  
  geom_line(aes(y=WUE16, color="WUE16"), linewidth=1.75) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=WUE19, color="WUE19"), linewidth=1.75) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=WUE27, color="WUE27"), linewidth=1.75) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=WUE17, color="WUE17"), linewidth=1.75) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=means, color="means"), span=0.2, fill="grey", linetype="twodash", linewidth=2) + 
  labs(color="Legend") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=colors)`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) you are much more likely to receive a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.
This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

```r
library("ggplot2")

means_cols <- c("WUE19", "WUE27", "WUE16", "WUE17")
means <- rowMeans(wue_r[means_cols])
wue_fin <- cbind(wue_r, means)

wue_fin |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(Year, means), names_to = "WUE") |> 
  ggplot(aes(Year, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = WUE), linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = means), color = "grey", linetype = "twodash", linewidth = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Test data

The test data is built-in data set `iris`, transformed.

```r
wue_r <- iris[1:50, -5]
names(wue_r) <- c("WUE19", "WUE27", "WUE16", "WUE17")
wue_r$Year <- 1970 + 1:50
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>